# Deleting a row from dynamic html table using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have saved few data from the view to database and added it to dynamically created html table using jquery in my asp.net mvc application. The script is given below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var attributetable = [];
    $("#AddAttrib").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#AttributeList").show();
        var attribute = $("#Attribute").val();
        var attributename = $("#Attribute option:selected").text();
        var documentId = $("#DocumentId").val();
        var instructionId = $("#InstructionId").val();

        var attributevalue = $("#text1").val();
        attributetable.push({
            attribute: attribute,
            attributevalue: attributevalue
        });
        var row = $("<tr></tr>");

        var contents = '<tr><td>' + attribute + '</td><td>' + attributename + '</td><td>' + attributevalue + '</td><td><a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>';
        $("#AttributeList").append(contents);

        var jsonToPost = {};
        jsonToPost.attribute = attribute;
        jsonToPost.attributename = attributename;
        jsonToPost.attributevalue = attributevalue;
        jsonToPost.documentId = documentId;
        jsonToPost.instructionId = instructionId;

        jsonToPostString = JSON.stringify(jsonToPost);
        alert(jsonToPostString);
        $.post("/Instruction/CreateInstnAttribute", { data: jsonToPostString });
    });
```

I need to delete the row when  "delete" is clicked. The requirement is to delete the row on clicking the delete link. how can i achieve it? 
Thanks for all helps in prior.

Answer (score 4):

It seems as though you are using the `"delete"` ID for more than one row. That is invalid. IDs must be unique. It should be a class instead.

```
<td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
```

Then if `AttributeList` is your `<table>`, you could place [a `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler on it to handle clicks on the `<a>` elements that have the class `"delete"`.

```
$("#AttributeList").delegate('a.delete', 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Place this inside your `$(document).ready()` call.

This [uses `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get its nearest `<tr>` ancestor, [then `.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the row.

It also [uses `e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault) to disable the default behavior of the `<a>` element.

Comment: thanks patrick. but am getting this error when view is loading 
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @Suja - What version of jQuery are you using? The delegate method was introduced in version `1.4.2`. You'll get that error if you're using an older version.